# Do Black Hair Fuzzy Caterpillars bite?

Tags: zoology

I saw a caterpillar in my bathroom. It's about 2 inches long and 3/4 inches in diameter. It has long (about 1 inches) long hair on his body.

I live in eastern India, Asia. I don't know if it was alive, as I didn't see any remarkable movement.

Are they dangerous? Do they bite? How to get rid of them?

Comment: It would be better if you would post some pictures of them

Comment: I can nearly guarantee that there are nearly zero species of caterpillar that have a nasty bite. Some caterpillars like the pine processionary cause skin rashes. some caterpillars can Kill you, better check it on this list: https://www.ranker.com/list/caterpillars-that-can-kill-you/eric-vega

Answer (score 2):

> I saw, it has long (about 1 inches) long hair on his body.

The hairs you refer to may be [urticating hairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urticating_hair), which can cause extreme itching & irritation. Without a picture of the caterpillar, I can't say for sure though; out of extra precaution, let's just assume they are (until an image is provided).

> Are they dangerous?

As long as you don't let the caterpillar hair come into contact with your bare skin/body, there should be no risk of harm. That being said, be mindful of indirect contact; i.e., perhaps picking the caterpillar up with your shirt sleeve, the hairs now being on the sleeve, then you wiping your face with your shirt sleeve later in the day. See [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66321/why-is-there-extreme-itching-when-we-touch-a-hairy-caterpillar-what-are-ways-to/66327#66327) for more information, including treatment, should said exposure ever occur.

> Do they bite?

Caterpillars do have the ability to bite, however, their bite isn't strong enough to pierce human skin. Nothing to worry about here..

> How to get rid of them?

To "get rid" of the caterpillar, I recommend getting a hard, thin surface - such as a piece of cardboard - ushering the caterpillar onto the surface, and then placing the caterpillar somewhere safe outside. If the caterpillar is in the process of [molting](http://www.butterfly-fun-facts.com/fun-facts/molting-caterpillars/), relocation can easily kill it, so please be diligent when attempting to relocate.